# MYSQL function to count the numbers of the last continues date

Tags: mysql, sql, function

I have a table like this...

```
jhm_remind_signin
(id INT PRIMARY KEY
,user_id INT
,remind_id INT
,signin_date DATETIME
,signin_cycle VARCHAR(20)
,is_delete TINYINT
,created_time DATETIME
,created_by INT
,updated_time DATETIME
,updated_by INT
);
```

...with relevant data like this...

```
signin_date
2016-03-03 14:24:02
2016-03-04 14:24:02
2016-03-05 14:24:02
2016-03-06 14:24:02
2016-03-07 14:24:02
2016-03-08 14:24:02
2016-03-09 14:24:02
2016-03-10 14:24:02
2016-03-11 14:24:02
2016-03-12 14:24:02
2016-03-13 14:24:02
2016-03-14 14:24:02
2016-03-15 14:24:02
2016-03-16 14:24:02
2016-03-18 14:24:02
2016-03-19 14:24:02
2016-03-20 14:24:02
```

I want to count the numbers of the last continues sign up date,if one day don't sign up we must recalculate the numbers.

So, I would like to have a result that looks like this...

Comment: I can count in java code,but I want to use sql .so I have no idea

Comment: No images thanks, just properly formatted questions

Comment: click"enter image description here" ,you can find the image,thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT @counter:=case @prev_date 
                 when DATE_ADD(signin_date, INTERVAL -1 DAY) then @counter+1 
                 else 0 end as continuous_count,
       @prev_date:=DATE(signin_date) 
FROM the_table
ORDER_BY signin_date
```

The select for each row calculates `continuous_count` - length of continuous days intervals.

You need the `continuous_count` value from last row

Comment: nice sql, but there is a little error ,I can't write sql like this,so I have no idea how to fix it.The erro is"[2016-03-03 16:25:36] [42000][1064] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@prev_date:=DATE(signin_date) as continuous_count
FROM jhm_remind_signin
ORDER_B' at line 4".

Answer (score -1):

i think it's impossible if use only sql. u could add one file like last_continues_signin_flag to this table. Then every time when you insert data , u can check current date with max sign_date in data , if this time is continue last_continues_signin_flag = 1 else last_continues_signin_flag = 0, so u can use this field to count as u want.

Comment: impossible is nothing